# How to read in polynomials and storing them in an array with error checking in C?

Tags: c

The function reads coefficients for the polynomial from standard input and stores them in the given array. The capacity parameter tells the function how much room the coeff[] array has for coefficients. The function tries to read all the coefficients it can until it reaches the end-of-file and returns the number of coefficients it actually reads. If the input polynomial is bad (e.g., with too many coefficients or with input that doesn't parse as a floating point number), this function will print "Invalid polynomial" and exit the program with a status of 101.

The input file is like this:

0.0 6.0

25.00 -47.50 25.17 -5.00 0.33

The first two numbers is the range of the plot and the second line represents the coefficients of the polynomial.

This is the code I have so far:

```
/**
 */

// Include our own header first
#include "poly.h"

// Then, anything else we need in the implementation file.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/** Exit status if the input polynomail is bad. */
#define INVALID_POLYNOMAIL_STATUS 101

int readPoly( int capacity, double coeff[] )
{
   double variable = 0.0;

   int ch;

   int count = 0;
  while ( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF ) {

    for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {


         if(scanf("%lf", &variable) != 1) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input");
            exit(101);
         }

          else {

                  coeff[i] = variable;

                  count++;
               } 
    }
 }
 return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*getchar* may read the beginning of a value, this is not correct like that

A simple way is to stop on any error (EOF or bad value) :

```
int readPoly( int capacity, double coeff[] )
{
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
      if (scanf("%lf", &coeff[i]) != 1)
        break;
   }

   return i;
}
```

An other way is to bypass by hand the spaces to be able to indicate an error :

```
int readPoly( int capacity, double coeff[] )
{
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
      for (;;) {
        int c;

        if ((c = getchar()) == EOF)
          return i;
        if (!isspace(c)) {
          ungetc(c, stdin);
          break;
      }
      if (scanf("%lf", &coeff[i]) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input");
        exit(101);
      }
   }

   return i;
}
```

Note *count* is redundant with *i*, just *i* is enough, and you can also directly *scanf* into the array

Comment: In the first example, how would I display a message? Because I need to display that error message when I get a bad value.

Comment: @AHunt if you want to indicate an error you have to use my second proposal, this is why I put it ;-)

Comment: What does the for (;;) statement do?

Comment: @AHunt is like `while(1)` or `for (;1;)` just to loop without a (real) condition, the goal is to bypass spaces and may be finish function

Comment: So this would get only the second line and store it in the array?

Comment: @AHunt I do not understand you, what you mean by _second line_?

Comment: The second line of input: 25.00 -47.50 25.17 -5.00 0.33. Also, where does the isspace function come from?

Comment: My proposal bypass the newline, so all numbers will be read, I supposed this is the goal. You have _isspace_ with `#include <ctype.h>`, if you do not have on your environment is it easy to implement comparing the char with space \t \n and \r for instance

Comment: I just need the second line since these are the coefficients of the function. The first line are the x values of the graph.

Comment: @AHunt in that case define a function reading a double in the same way I do in the second proposal and call it two times before to memorize in the array to bypass the first two values, you can also bypass the first line if you are sure of the format of the input